# electron webpack Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined "querystring"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, electron

I'm trying to run [an old electron app](https://github.com/belgacea/graffiti/tree/develop), but I can't figure out which node version to use, nor which part of the config/dependencies to update.

I added electron `webPreferences` in the windows, but it didn't help.

```js
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
```

Does someone have any idea of what to check first ? Should I try to fix warnings in the current state of the app or should I update dependencies and then fix major breaks ?

**yarn dev**

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack-dev-server --hot --watch --config webpack.config.dev.js
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from http://localhost:8080/
i ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.4.4 from typescript
i ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from ./tsconfig.json
i ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.4.4 from typescript
i ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from ./tsconfig.json
i ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
i ｢atl｣: Time: 3514ms
i ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
i ｢atl｣: Time: 2355ms
‼ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 4697290ef706a2a99ad5e1b5fab076995682e95f
Version: webpack 4.30.0
Child
    Hash: 4697290ef706a2a99ad5
    Time: 17242ms
    Built at: 2023-05-24 15:55:15
        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  6.53 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
    Entrypoint main = bundle.js
    [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/index.tsx 52 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/mousetrap/mousetrap.js] 33.1 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js] 416 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 8.26 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.59 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 KiB {main} [built]
    [./src/index.tsx] 7.99 KiB {main} [built]
        + 695 hidden modules

    WARNING in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/options/misc.js 27:21-40
    Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/fluent-ffmpeg.js
     @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
     @ ./src/common/Util.js
     @ ./src/views/Duplicates.tsx
     @ ./src/index.tsx
Child
    Hash: e1b5fab076995682e95f
    Time: 13857ms
    Built at: 2023-05-24 15:55:11
            Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    background.js  4.33 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
    Entrypoint main = background.js
    [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./background.ts 52 bytes {main} [built]
    [./background.ts] 1010 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 8.26 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.59 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 KiB {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.11 KiB {main} [built]
    [./src/background/BackgroundWindow.ts] 10.1 KiB {main} [built]
    [./src/main/Logger.js] 1010 bytes {main} [built]
    [querystring] external "querystring" 42 bytes {main} [built]
        + 586 hidden modules

    WARNING in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/options/misc.js 27:21-40
    Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/fluent-ffmpeg.js
     @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
     @ ./src/background/ScreenshotEngine.ts
     @ ./src/background/BackgroundWindow.ts
     @ ./background.ts

    WARNING in ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in '.\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
     @ ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
     @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
     @ ./src/background/Watcher.ts
     @ ./src/background/BackgroundWindow.ts
     @ ./background.ts
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

Console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (external_"querystring":1:18)
    at Object.querystring (bundle.js:8870:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:703:30)
    at fn (bundle.js:77:20)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///(:8080/webpack)-dev-server/client?:6:19)
    at eval (webpack:///(:8080/webpack)-dev-server/client?:299:30)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080 (bundle.js:7798:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:703:30)
    at fn (bundle.js:77:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(:8080/webpack)-dev-server/client?:1:1)
```

**yarn start**

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron .

process.env.NODE_ENV: development
Done in 72.06s.
```

Console:

```
bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
.\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\security-warnings.js:170 Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
    Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
    this app to unnecessary security risks.
 
For more information and help, consult
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
 This warning will not show up
once the app is packaged.
```

Node

```
$ nvm list

    16.10.0
    14.21.3
    14.17.0
    12.4.0
  * 10.15.3 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    10.8.0
    10.3.0
    9.11.2
    8.9.4
```

**Edit:**

I used node 10.15.3 because that's the version chatgpt recommended me based on the dependency lists.. and the readme indicates to use node > 8. But I have no clue of which to use, nor which dependency to update in priority.
Should I start with electron, then webpack & typescript ? or maybe the dependency with warnings like fluent-ffmpeg, chokidar & fsevents ?

Also is there any centralized reference for javascript dependency compatibility ? or any tool that would help me identify conflicts & resolve them ?

**Edit 2:**

I can't to get node version from the `renderer.js` using electron 5 & node 12.18 and the [example](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) is for electron 24.

`yarn dev` (console)

```
renderer.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: versions is not defined
```

`yarn start` (console)

```
.\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:177 Unable to load preload script: .\preload.js
(anonymous) @ .\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:177

.\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:178 TypeError: Cannot read property 'exposeInMainWorld' of undefined
(anonymous) @ .\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:178

renderer.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: versions is not defined
    at renderer.js:2
```

**Edit 3:**

I've made some "progress". After updating electron to v6, I got the following error: `Error: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled`

I tried to reenable context isolation in the windows: `contextIsolation: true,`
And then I got (almost) the result I was looking for: This app is using Chrome (v76.0.3809.146), Node.js (v12.4.0), and Electron (v6.1.12)
Except I'm using node v12.18 as the electron release docs recommends.

Then I tried to load the app bundle back again in the `index.html`, making reference on :

- `./dist/bundle.js`
- `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js`

But I still get the same error :

`yarn start` : bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

`yarn dev` : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Is it because I need to move and expose all [IpcHandlers](https://github.com/belgacea/graffiti/blob/develop/main.js#LL203C1-L203C1) and all the files under src/common/ in the `preload.js` file using the `contextBridge` and `ipcRenderer` like :

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('Constants', {
    IpcEvents: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('IpcEvents'),
    ping: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('ping')
})
```

Or is it a completely different problem like some missing path or webpack config related issue ?

I tested to add a ping handler in the `main.js` but then I get an error `ipcMain.handle is not a function`
I read about the [IPC patterns](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload#communicating-between-processes) but it is [a lot](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to fully understand all at once, especially with way it has been done in the app..

Also, electron v6 [require()ing node builtins in sandboxed renderers no longer implicitly loads the remote version.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#api-changed-requireing-node-builtins-in-sandboxed-renderers-no-longer-implicitly-loads-the-remote-version)
Should I replace all the `require` by `require('electron').remote.require` in js and ts/x files ? Or only client side ?

Comment: As an user of this app, I wanted to put it back on the right tracks to add some features (like sorting options) at first, but now I also would like to prevent security risks. I will try to follow electron latest best practices once I fixed the build from all the deprecated imports, as I am sure it will require a lot more refactoring then.
`yarn start` works but I get the following error in the DevTool console (and the app is not rendered properly)
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED bundle.js:1`

Comment: You can't get it working because, as the error says `Cannot read property 'exposeInMainWorld' of undefined`, the `contextBridge` api is not present in electron 5, contrary to what chat gpt told me. I actually found it in v6, so give it a try.

Comment: Thank you again, I tried electron v6 but I still get the same error when loading `bundle.js` in electron

Comment: Regarding your bundle.js load problem, use https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/. It makes it easy to keep index.html in sync with your bundled code. Ad `ipcMain.handle is not a function`, it's really what it says, `handle` doesn't exist. Instead, you can use `on` or `addListener`. Btw. for the future I recommend using typescript since this is the 2nd time you missed invalid method call.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go point by point:

> I can't figure out which node version to use, nor which part of the config/dependencies to update.

You are using electron 4 which packs Node v10.11, so you can use Node 10 in the meantime.

If you want to upgrade to electron version which is currently supported (as you should), have a look at the [releases table](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/electron-timelines). Upgrading to the latest one would require you to use the latest LTS Node (18 at the time of the writing) as well and your next steps should lead to [Breaking Changes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes) so that you can adapt to the relevant ones and take it from there.

One of the relevant ones for you is that since electron 5, it's very much discouraged to use Node APIs or communicate with main process in the renderer process directly, and one should use [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) instead.

That of course requires a big refactoring in your codebase, so you can for the time being indeed make it work via:

```
 webPreferences: {
   nodeIntegration: true,
   contextIsolation: false
 }
```

which exposes Node APIs to renderer process, and doesn't separate it from the main's context.

> yarn dev & Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Since your client-side code heavily uses both electron and Node APIs, it can't run in the browser, which is the case when you use `yarn dev` and then go to `localhost:8080`. Browser doesn't have access to Node APIs like `require()` and throws the error from above as a result.

That's why running `yarn start` works (somewhat) fine, because it starts electron, which thanks to the config above exposes the Node APIs to the renderer (client-side).

If you perform the refactoring and use the `contextBridge`, ie. clean your client-side code from all electron and Node references, you will be in the best shape to run the client-side code in the browser (with some api mocking).

> Should I start with electron, then webpack & typescript ? or maybe the dependency with warnings like fluent-ffmpeg, chokidar & fsevents ?

I'd ignore the warning, because chances are good they just disappear once you ugrade electron.

Upgrading TypeScript is actually up to you, whether you want to take advantage of the new features it offers, and it's completely optional.

You also doesn't have to upgrade Webpack (you have version 3 currently - old but works) but you might find it easier down the line to use something more modern, either higher version or something faster like Vite, but it's not a requirement.

> Also is there any centralized reference for javascript dependency compatibility ?

Only as specified by library authors, which gets to be checked by package managers like NPM at the time of install.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advices. I'm trying to understand [context isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation), but I still can't make it work with the `preload.js` script. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

[querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) is a built-in module for node.js, you need to check your dependency packages, for web consider using [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) instead.

Comment: As surprising as it sounds, `querystring` is not called or import anywhere in the project... The only reference I found is in `yarn.lock` file